# Vimeo API Get Video by Tag

Tags: php, api, vimeo

I have been following the [documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getByTag/playground) for the Vimeo API to query the API for videos with a certain tag, I have gone ahead and tagged a video with the key word dumbbells.

Unfortunately its returning all my videos, can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

**Code**

```
$vimeo->request("/users/myid/videos?method=vimeo.videos.getByTag&tag=dumbell");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be mixing two different APIs: the [new Vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api) and the [deprecated Vimeo Advanced API](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced)<sup>1</sup>. The endpoint has the structure of the newer API, but  the parameters appear to be taken from the older API (e.g., `method` isn't going to be a parameter in the newer API, since it's functionality is dictated by the endpoint itself).

In theory, you should be able to use the `query` parameter on the [`/users/{user_id}/videos` endpoint](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/users), but I didn't have success when testing this (using the parameter always resulted in 0 results, could be a bug).

<sup>1</sup> "This API is deprecated and no longer accessible. Check out our brand-new API (it’s way better anyway)."